# Is there any other footage (or pictures) of Henry Victor as the Saxon Warrior in 'The Mummy'?

Tags: movie, character-identification, the-mummy-1932

In the classic horror-fantasy film *The Mummy* (1932), it is well known that there were several filmed scenes of the different eras where the princess Ankh-es-en-amon reincarnated but for reasons of time they were [discarded before the film was released](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3YOuRyq_08).

It seems that film silent actor Henry Victor, whose name appeared in the initial credits of the film as 'the Saxon Warrior', performed in one of those deleted scenes. The still below shows the actress Zita Johann portraying the princess along with Vikings with horned helmets and lot of fur. Probably this is the scene where Victor performed as a boyfriend or suitor of the princess.

Are there any other still pictures, posters or footage showing Henry Victor as *the Saxon Warrior*?

[image]

Comment: I've tried to make the question a little more clearly worded.